# Syntax explanation with pointers as function parameters (C++)

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm not sure if I can ask basic questions here, but I am starting to learn C++ and do not understand one little thing in pointers syntax.

Here is the sample of my code:

```
using namespace std;

int randomname(int *x);

int main(){

    int a = 1;

    int *ab;

    ab = &a;

    randomname(&a);

}


int randomname(int *x){

    *x = 9001;

}
```

My question is about the * symbol. Why in the main function on line *ab = &a;* I don't need the *, but on line **x = 9001;* I need it? I think syntax should be same in both functions, but it isn't. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Basic questions are fine as long as they fit the guidelines, such as showing that you've put effort into it and providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where applicable. In this case, every single C++ book meant to teach the basics of the language will go into depth on when and why you need the asterisk.

Comment: Regardless of the difficulty of your question, you must always research it yourself. You can find this answer easily here on SO or with a quick google search.

Comment: Here's a list of [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Everything you are asking should be covered in an introductory one.

Comment: This is a trivial question that can easily be answered by any text book/google search

Comment: Well I tried to search for it. Unfortunately I am not native english speaker so I did not find the answer. ("pointers as function arguments in c++" did not gave me rezults that I was looking for :( ) P.S. I am learnig C++ with videos on youtube, and this question was not covered somehow

Comment: I think it is a fair question from someone who is starting with the language, because the meaning of both symbols changes depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of both the asterisk `*` and the ampersand `&` changes depending on the context. Their meanings in expressions and in declarations are different:

- When `*` is used in a *declaration*, it designates a pointer
- When `&` is used in a *declaration*, it designates a reference
- When `*` is used in an *expression*, it performs a pointer dereference of its operand
- When `&` is used in an *expression*, it obtains a pointer of its operand

Once you understand these distinctions, you can tell that

1. Line `int *ab` is a *declaration*. Asterisk designates `ab` as a pointer.
2. Line `ab = &a;` has an *expression*. `&` takes `a`'s pointer, and assigns it to `ab`, which has a pointer type specified at the time of its declaration (above).
3. Line `*x = 9001` is also an *expression*, making the asterisk a dereference operator. You use the asterisk to tell the compiler that the target of the assignment is whatever is pointed to by `x`, not `x` itself.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand it now. Somehow I can only accept your answer only after 1 minute :/

Answer (score 1):

You need the asterisk when you are declaring a pointer, or when you are dereferencing the pointer. The syntax actually is the same in both functions, but what is being assigned in each of the assignment statements is different.

An `int` is a value. An `int` variable is stored in a storage location. A pointer to an `int` is also a value, but its value refers to a storage location. When you are performing an assignment with a pointer, you could assign the value of the pointer itself (the address of the storage location it refers to), or you could assign a value to the storage location it refers to.

In the case of `int *x` in the formal parameters of the function, or in the declaration `int *ab` that defines the `ab` variable, you need the asterisk because you are declaring a variable or a parameter to be of type "pointer to int".

In the assignment `ab = &a` you do not need the asterisk because you are assigning the *address of variable `a` to the pointer `ab`* -- you are assigning the value of the pointer itself, not what it points to.

In the assignment `*x = 9001`, you need the asterisk to get the storage location that the pointer refers to. This is called "dereferencing" the pointer. You are not assigning a value to the pointer itself, but instead you are assigning a value to the storage location to which the pointer refers, which is the storage allocated for variable `a` in function `main`.

This article by Eric Lippert may be of considerable help to you:

> [What are the fundamental rules of pointers?](http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/#more-2137)